# C++: Containers of Arbitrary Template Type

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, containers

In C++, suppose I have a templatized class, like

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
    ...
};
```

and suppose that I have several kinds of Foo objects, like

```
Foo<int> intFoo = Foo<int>();
Foo<double> doubleFoo = Foo<double>();
...
```

and so on.

Actually, its worse than that. I really want an intFoo object of a class that inherits from Foo< int >, for instance.

I would like to do something like this:

```
std::vector<Foo<?> > aVector;
aVector.push_back(intFoo);
aVector.push_back(doubleFoo);
```

Keeping in mind that I have substantially oversimplified my design case, is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to have your Foo inheriting from an empty base class

```
struct CommonBase {};

template<typename T>
class Foo : public CommonBase
{ 
    // ... 
};
```

and then have a container of pointers to the common base

```
vector<CommonBase*> v;
```

If you want to keep away from inheritance, you could use `boost:any` to store any type in your container.

An interesting topic to look into (if you want to manually implement this kind of things) is **type erasure**

Answer (score 1):

`Foo<int>` and `Foo<double>` are 2 different classes despite they share the name `Foo`, so you can't just put them to `vector` as is. But you can use `boost::variant` and store a vector of variants.